# UK visa for three days for Bangaldeshi citizen travelling from Brussels

Tags: standard-visitor-visas, bangladeshi-citizens

I am a Bangladeshi national and have a visa for Belgium. Now I want to visit UK for a week. I have friends there but I don't want their help.

How I can have UK visa in this case, for example through hotel booking etc.?

Will hotel give me confirmation email of booking even if I do not pay?

Comment: See http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/visiting/general/ for the procedure to apply for a UK visa.